# bad value for attribute "action" on element "form": illegal charachter in path segment: "<" is not allowed

Tags: php, html

From the w3 validator

bad value for attribute "action" on element "form": illegal character in path segment: "<" is not allowed.

This is sending me nuts! I am trying to find the mistake already two hours but all seems fine.

```
    <form id="contact" method="post" action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

illegal character in path segment: "<" is not allowed. I tried to find the w3school error but haven't find the solution yet.
Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>`?

Comment: mmm , why this ` action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" accept-charset="UTF-8"` ? you can put it like this `<form action="" method="post">` or this `<form action="name of the page that the php code in" method="post">`

Comment: @NathanRobb. What do you mean for output? I'm creating a PHP file that can handle the form data when submitted. I'm a newbie and as such I have dumb questions)

Answer (score 1):

The PHP code should not go through the validator.
You should take the HTML output (after it's been processed by the PHP interpreter) and put *that* into the validator.

If that's the actual code that gets send to your browser, you should probably check your server setup as PHP does not seem to be processing the page.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with validation, your answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Nathan the question explicitly states that there's an error from the w3cvalidator

Comment: You're saying "put that into the validator". He's not putting anything into any validator, it's an action attribute on a form.

Comment: @NathanRobb — It's an action attribute on a form start tag in a PHP program … which is being fed to the validator. The first line of the question says the error message comes from the validator, you don't get error messages from the validator unless you put something into it, if you put that PHP source code into the validator then you get the error message quoted in the question.

Comment: Yes. And obviously he's putting the piece of Code He has provided into the validator. And that's unprocessed PHP Code. So if He wants valid results, He needs to grab the processed source. That's what I wanted to say.

Comment: Oh, I see. perhaps you should reword that, it sounds way different.

Comment: To be more clear this is the second part of the message but I tried all sorts of possibilities and nothing.Any URL. For example: /hello, #canvas, or http://example.org/. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20. Common non-alphanumeric characters other than ! $ & ' ( ) * +  - . / : ; = ? @ _ ~ generally must be percent-encoded. For example, the pipe character (|) must be encoded as %7C.